# Using FirebaseAuth verifyPhoneNumber in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hey I am trying to use Firebase Auth `verifyPhoneNumber` in Flutter.

I am constantly getting my `msg` in `onTap` function as null. I tried declaring a variable in `registerToFb` function but I am not able to update its value. How do I solve it?

Following is the function from where I am calling the `firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNymber()` method.

```
onTap: () async {
       setState(() => isLoading = true);
       String msg = await _auth.registerToFb(
        "+91$truephoneNumber", context);
       print(msg);

    },
```

Following is where I am defining my function.

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Future registerToFb(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) async {
    String result = " ";
    await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        UserCredential authresult =
            await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

        User user = authresult.user;
        _getUserFromFirebase(user);
        result =  "signedUp";
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        String error = e.code == 'invalid-phone-number'
            ? "Invalid number. Enter again."
            : "Can Not Login Now. Please try again.";
        result = error;
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
       
        result = "verified";
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Help me, please. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to return the error as well, might that solve it?

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `registerToFb`. The `return` bits you do have are referring to the closure functions, not the `registerToFb` function.

Comment: @lrsvmb thanks for your suggestion and sorry for the mistake. I forgot to use return there.but even with ` return error ` its not working.

Comment: Abion47 I tried returning the error value from the function but it is still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't returning anything in your function. And even when you try to save a value from inside the callbacks, the future from `verifyPhoneNumber` resolves before those callbacks get called.

You need to be awaiting the right thing. You shouldn't await the future returned from `verifyPhoneNumber`. You should await a new future that doesn't resolve until you get a result from one of the callbacks. This means you need to create your own `Future` which you can manually resolve specifically when you need it to. You can do this with a `Completer`:

```dart
Future<String> registerToFb(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) {
  final completer = Completer<String>();

  _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
      UserCredential authresult =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      User user = authresult.user;
      _getUserFromFirebase(user);
      completer.complete("signedUp");
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      String error = e.code == 'invalid-phone-number'
          ? "Invalid number. Enter again."
          : "Can Not Login Now. Please try again.";
      completer.complete(error);
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
      completer.complete("verified");
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
      completer.complete("timeout");
    },
  );

  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: My tests with `verifyPhoneNumber` showed that the function provided for codeAutoRetrievalTimeout can be called even when the function provided for `codeSent` has already been called. For your code this means that `complete` can be called twice, and the documentation says 'Calling [complete] or [completeError] must be done at most once.' Not sure what will happen next, but I guess this will end with an exception.

Comment: @mic That behavior is odd, and I'd suspect that that's a bug in the Firebase package. You are correct, though, as calling `complete` on an already completed `Completer` results in an error, specifically a `StateError` with the message `"Bad state: Future already completed"`. As a workaround for now, you can check `completer.isCompleted` before calling `complete` in each of those callbacks to prevent that error from occurring.